# Mouse as an Ancient Remedy - Official Critique

Tags: roman-empire, ancient-egypt

The mice has been extensively used in ancient times as a healing remedy; Claudius Galenus (AD 129-200) quoted from Cleopatra’s book on cosmetics: 
“The following is the best of all, acting for fallen hairs ... Of domestic mice burnt, one part...”

It is clear, however, that chopped up mice is not an effective remedy. I need a **citable** source (preferably an article) that critiques the use of a mouse as a remedy. Due to the obscure nature of my query, google searches haven't been able to find me any critiques.

Can someone point me to a modern article that refutes or praises the ancient use of a mouse as a remedy?

Comment: Does the article need to be modern? (not that I know the answer anyway)

Comment: Yeah, sorry (anything after 1900 would be okay)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a source request.  A kind of question explicitly excluded by the rules for this stackexchange.

Comment: @SamuelRussell - slightly reworded, it'd be a good fit for Skeptics.SE